# Prolog - substitute substring of string by letter not used in string itself

Tags: prolog, substitution, swi-prolog

I am searching some predicate `substitute(+StringInput, +SubString, -Substitution, -SubstitutionLetter)`, whereby all the substrings identic with `+SubString` occuring in `+StringInput` are substituted by a individual symbol not occuring in `+StringInput` itself. The result is given by `-Substition` and the individualsymbol is stored in `-SubstitionLetter`.

e.g.

```
+StringInput = "(2 + b) + c * 2"  
+SubString = "2"
-Substitution = "(a + b) + c * a"
-SubstitutionLetter = "a"
```

or

```
+StringInput= "I went to school on Monday, if I don't get sick."
+Substring = "I"
-Substitution = "a1 went to school on Monday, if a1 don't get sick."
-SubstitutionLetter = "a1"
```

Comment: Is *a1* provided, or meant to be computed somehow?

Comment: It is not provided, thanks for answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/73611612/ for better code.

```
% Show lists of codes as text
:- portray_text(true).
% Show 100 chars before truncating
:- set_portray_text(ellipsis, _, 100).

% Replace if match found
replace(Find, Replace), Replace --> Find, !, replace(Find, Replace).
% Otherwise accept char-by-char
replace(Find, Replace), [C] --> [C], !, replace(Find, Replace).
% Accept success when reached end
replace(_Find, _Replace) --> [].
```

Then, can use e.g.:

```
?- phrase(replace(`I`, `a1`), `I went to school on Monday, if I don't get sick.`, R).
R = `a1 went to school on Monday, if a1 don't get sick.`.
```

This works if both the *find* and *replace* text are provided.

These are [lists of codes](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=text-representation), i.e.:

```
?- `ab` = [97,98].
true.
```